# Pronounciation of a certain part of prayer

Tags: salat, pronunciation

In salat, when you come back (stand up) from Ruku', you say:

"Samiallahu liman **hamida**"

Is it pronounced "hammida" or "hameeda"?

I pronounced it hammida, so I am not sure if it is correct or not.

Comment: For people who transcribe سَمِعَ اللّهُ لِمَنْ حَمِدَهُ for english prounounciation it could be **same'a Allahu leman hamedah** for those who pronounce the latin letters as is like in latin/french/german it would sound like **sami'a allahu liman hamidah** (there's a litely prounounced "h" at the end! As english does only prounounce the "a" as in latin at the beginnig of a word and the english "e" is equal to the latin "i". And as there's no shiddah in Arabic we don't have any doube consonant!

Answer (score 1):

```
            In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

In order to elucidate the issue you'd better pay heed that according to the correct Arabic grammar, the exact pronunciation of Same'allah-o Leman "**Hamedah**" is **Hamedah** (حمده). Of course, it seems that in Arabic language, most of Arab people pronounce the letter "E" as/like "I". For instance, the word Mohammed is written Muhammed, but some Arabs pronounce it as if they are saying Mohammid! Otherwise as I illustrated before, the precise pronunciation of the mentioned word is Hamedah as it is written Hamedah in its Arabic text.

Namely it is written in Arabic like the following phrase:

> «سَمِعَ اللّهُ لِمَنْ حَمِدَهُ»

---

**Conclusion:**

It can be inferred from the main Arabic text of the above-mentioned phrase that HAMEDAH is the most right form of that (although based on some Arabic accents it is heard as Hemidah).

---

**Reference:**

- [www.aviny.com](http://www.aviny.com/ahkam/ResalehVahidKhorasani/resale16.aspx)

Comment: @TruthSeeker, the link of the reference? I test it again, it is Okay for me and practicable. (by the way, the presented link is in Persian (Farsi). Good luck mate.